# GlobalScope coroutine not logging error to console

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Why is the code below not logging to the console a TimeoutCancellationException?

```
@Test fun noExceptionLogged(){
    GlobalScope.launch{
        withTimeout(4000) {
            repeat(1000) { i ->
                println("I'm sleeping $i ...")
                delay(500L)
            }
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(20_000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it works like this due to `GlobalScope` nature. It cannot be canceled so it swallows `CancellationException`.

```
GlobalScope.launch { // won't print anything
    throw CancellationException()
}

GlobalScope.launch { // will print stacktrace
    throw RuntimeException()
}

runBlocking { // will print stackrace
    throw RuntimeException()
}

GlobalScope.launch { // will print "Hello!"
    try {
        throw CancellationException()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Hello!")
    }
}
```